# Multiple Solr environments with one Zookeeper ensemble

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

We have two Solr environments in production. 
One Solr environment has latest two years data. Other has last 10 years of archived data. 
At the moment, these two Solr environments connect to separate Zookeeper ensembles.

The collections have same name & configuration in both Solr environments.
We want to reduce the number of servers for Zookeeper.

Is it feasible to have both Solr environments in production connect to one Zookeeper ensemble without overwriting configs for each other? 
Or is it mandatory to have separate Zookeeper ensemble for each Solr environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same Zookeeper ensemble to handle more than one Solr or SolrCloud instance.

However, the data must be kept separate.  This is (probably) best done by using the "chroot" functionality in Zookeeper.

Essentially, when you create the "space" in Zookeeper for your Solr instance, you append a /some_thing_unique and keep that in the appropriate config files in Solr - then you should have no trouble.

I haven't experienced moving an existing Solr instance from one Zookeeper to another - I'd guess you would have to take Solr down, change the configs, set up the collection etc.. in Zookeeper, and restart Solr.  For sure I'd get that all worked out in a test environment before doing it live.

Hope that helps...

Oh, here's how I did it when creating a collection "new" in Zookeeper...  You'll note I gave it a name (the name of my collection) as well as noting what version of Solr I was using.  This allows me to install later versions of Solr and move my collection to that later version and keep it all in the same Zookeeper ensemble...

/opt/solr/server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost 10.196.12.103,10.196.12.104,10.196.22.103 -cmd makepath /myCollectionName_solr6_2